# Bing's Search Engine but Google's New Tab on Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, bing

Is it possible to make Bing the default search engine but keep Google's new tab page? If so, how can I do it?

I prefer Bing's search engine over Google's, but prefer Google's new tab page over Bing's. I tried searching on Bing, Google, and Stack Exchange, but I didn't find an answer.

Here's an image of the Google's new tab I'm talking about:
[image: Google's new tab]

Answer (score 1):

An alternative option (though may not 100% meet your need): simply set new tab page to blank,
by using extension "Blank New Tab Page" https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jaadjnlkjnhohljficgoddcjmndjfdmi

This will bring a completely clean and fast new tab, making the browser a pure browser, instead of a messy media playground.

Answer (score 0):

#### Is it possible to make Bing the default search engine but keep Google's new tab page?

Yes.

- Download and install the Chrome [New Tab Redirect](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tab-redirect/icpgjfneehieebagbmdbhnlpiopdcmna) extension.
- Configure the extension to use `https://www.google.com` as the Redirect URL for a new tab and click Save:

  > [image]
- Restart Chrome

  > [image]

Comment: It's not the same as Google's new tab page, but it's better than Bing's. I'll update my question to include a picture of the new tab I'm talking about.

Comment: Your image is what I see now. I've added a screen shot.

Comment: Here's what I get from following your directions: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JreS.png

Comment: Did you allow the permissions and restart Chrome?

Comment: Yes, I have allowed permissions and restarted Chrome.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. It works for me.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for trying.